# GPT4All failed to load model - invalid model file

Tags: python, langchain, gpt4all, pygpt4all

I Installed the GPT4All Installer using GUI based installers for Mac.

Then, I downloaded the required LLM models and take note of the PATH they're installed to.

Now I'm trying to load the models through a python application using streamlit.

Here is my `app.py` file:

```py
# Import app framework
import streamlit as st

# Import dependencies
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.llms import GPT4All

# Path to weights
PATH = "/Users/toto/Library/Application Support/nomic.ai/GPT4All/GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin"

# Instance of llm
llm = GPT4All(model=PATH, verbose=True)

# Prompt template
prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=['question'],
                        template="""
                        Question: {question}
                        
                        Answer: Let's think step by step  
                        """)

# LLM chain
chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)

# Title
st.title(' GPT For Y\'all')

# Prompt text box
prompt = st.text_input('Enter your prompt here!')

# if we hit enter do this
if prompt: 
  # Pass the prompt to the LLM chain
  response = chain.run(prompt)
  
  st.write(response)
```

When I'm running `streamlit run app.py` I get the following message:

```
  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Local URL: http://localhost:8501
  Network URL: http://10.81.128.79:8501

llama_model_load: loading model from '/Users/toto/Library/Application Support/nomic.ai/GPT4All/GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin' - please wait ...
llama_model_load: invalid model file '/Users/toto/Library/Application Support/nomic.ai/GPT4All/GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin' (unsupported format version 3, expected 1)
llama_init_from_file: failed to load model
[1]    3908 segmentation fault  streamlit run app.py
```

What's weird is that it's correctly work from the GPT4All desktop app but not from python code.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter similar situation yesterday.

We set the torch version as torch==2.0.1

See if this can help you.

Comment: It does not change anything ...